# Icon overlay in Finder for Icon Views other than Arrange By Name

Tags: cocoa

I have icon overlays working in Finder using mac_inject through the drawImage: method of the class IKImageBrowserCell (I also have the various list views working).

When Finder is switched into Arrange By Kind (or anything other than Arrange By Name) then the icon overlays no longer work.

Has anybody figured out what class needs to be used for these other views? I've been experimenting for days with no luck.

Comment: sorry dont get you .. you have hooked into com.apple.Finder or what? Why? There is icon services which can do overlays just fine

Answer (score 0):

If your question is still actual, there are perfect tool called **liferay-nativity** hosted in [github](https://github.com/liferay/liferay-nativity). It's cross platform, open source tool for adding icon overlay. It works with Finder very well.

https://github.com/liferay/liferay-nativity